# Angularjs $scope variables not updating in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angularjs and im trying to update two $scope variables in two seperate functions which are called on ng-click.

Even though the variables update, they wont rebind in the view.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     <p> <a href="#" ng-click="getDetails();getElse()">Refresh</a> </p>
    <p ng-controller="MainCtrl"><span ng-bind="something"></span></p>
       <p ng-controller="MainCtrl"><span ng-bind="somethingelse"></span></p>
</div>
</div>
```

**JS**
    function MainCtrl($scope) {

```
$scope.something = "something";
$scope.somethingelse = "else";

$scope.getDetails = function () {
     alert("getdetails before change: "+$scope.something);
    $scope.something = 'changed';
    alert("getdetails: "+$scope.something);
};

$scope.getElse = function () {
    alert("getElse before change: "+$scope.somethingelse);
    $scope.somethingelse = 'changed';
    alert("getElse: "+$scope.somethingelse);
    };

}
```

I've created a fiddle to show you what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/M3pZ8/

can anyone tell me what is the correct way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because you have `MainCtrl` declared 3 times, effectively creating 3 separate scopes. You only need it once, at the top.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p> <a href="#" ng-click="getDetails();getElse()">Refresh</a> </p>
    <p><span ng-bind="something"></span></p>
    <p><span ng-bind="somethingelse"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Each use of ng-controller creates a new instance of the controller. So, if you visit the same route three different times, you're going to have three different instances of the controller. This is a key distinction with a Service, which is persistent so that you get the same instance each time you inject it, throughout the application life-cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M3pZ8/2/)

```
 don't need to add same controller multiple times.
```